# Number of common values between two ranges counted only once each

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, unique

I have two numerical value ranges, say A1:G2:

| COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D | COLUMN E | COLUMN F | COLUMN G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 114 | 101 | 32 | 87 | 61 | 138 |
| 3 | 45 | 12 | 101 | 80 | 29 | 61 |

and A5:G6:

| COLUMN A | COLUMN B | COLUMN C | COLUMN D | COLUMN E | COLUMN F | COLUMN G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61 | 101 | 87 | 50 | 114 | 99 | 20 |
| 114 | 32 | 138 | 61 | 15 | 83 | 72 |

I want to count how many common numerical values between the two ranges but counted only once each (e.g. 61/101/114 occurring twice in one of the ranges but to be counted only once)

In J9 I have the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A5:G6,A1:G2)=0,0,IF(COUNTIF(A5:G6,A1:G2)>=1,1)))
```

giving 9 as a result, which is wrong, as there are only 7 common numerical values between the two ranges: 15,32,61,87,101,114,138. I believe this is due to values being counted twice.

I have also tried to count double occurrences with 0.5:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A5:G6,A1:G2)=0,0,IF(COUNTIF(A5:G6,A1:G2)=1,1,0.5)))
```

which however gives 7.5...

Your help would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted then one could try the following formulas to get the count of 7 for common numerical values, and counting the dupes as once each :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A8</kbd>

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(HSTACK(
 IFS(COUNTIFS(A1:G2,A5:G6)>=1,A5:G6),
 IFS(COUNTIFS(A5:G6,A1:G2)>=1,A1:G2)),3)))
```

---

This following formula returns those values you need, by wrapping within <kbd>ROWS()</kbd> gives us the count which you are looking for and as shown above:

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(HSTACK(
 IFS(COUNTIFS(A1:G2,A5:G6)>=1,A5:G6),
 IFS(COUNTIFS(A5:G6,A1:G2)>=1,A1:G2)),3))
```

---

Also if you need those which are more than once then just change the operator value from `>=1` to just `>1`

[image]

---

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(HSTACK(
     IFS(COUNTIFS(A1:G2,A5:G6)>1,A5:G6),
     IFS(COUNTIFS(A5:G6,A1:G2)>1,A1:G2)),3))
```

---

Or, only non matching then

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(HSTACK(
        IFS(COUNTIFS(A1:G2,A5:G6)=0,A5:G6),
        IFS(COUNTIFS(A5:G6,A1:G2)=0,A1:G2)),3))
```

---

One another way you could try:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A9</kbd>

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(TOCOL(A2:G3),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TOCOL(A2:G3),TOCOL(A6:G7))))))
```

---

OP Says:

> *thanks, Mayukh. All formulas you have suggested give #CALC! error for*
> *some ranges, though –  bluetick*

---

> *the #CALC! error appears when there are no common values between the*
> *two ranges –  bluetick*

---

To keep everything documented, guided what they need to do while there is no common values, by wrapping within a function <kbd>IFERROR()</kbd> screenshot attached as well about the discussions.

[image]

---

**Test Case:** When no match

[image]

---

Comment: thanks, Mayukh. All formulas you have suggested give #CALC! error for some ranges, though

Comment: Screenshot above clearly shows works as per the data posted in OP, if you have something else, then how can I tell. Tell me? Also have you tried to evaluate the formulas why it is returning `#CALC!` . If there is completely no match it will return `#CALC!` error for that you wrap it within `IFERROR()` which will output as `0`

Comment: the #CALC! error appears when there are no common values between the two ranges

Comment: @bluetick yes please read my last comment. Well it is assumed that you will have at least one common value(s). Hence that is why I mentioned, if you are getting error that means neither of the range has common values, so wrap with in `IFERROR()`

Comment: indeed, thanks so much, formula now working perfectly!